# Matlab getrect function - How to skip the mouse input

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

In Matlab GUI, I need a user mouse input as a rectangle that I have to plot on the axes1.

For this, I have code below:

```
   axes(handles.axes1);
   filename = 'A';
   img = imread(filename);
   imshow(img);
   hold on;
   rect_cord = getrect(handles.axes1);
   rectangle('Curvature', [0 0],'Position', [rect_cord],'EdgeColor',[1 0 0]);
```

This code runs fine (takes user input and plots the rectangle). However, for some images I don't want to get the user input from mouse (using getrect). In this case, how to skip the getrect function and move on to next image?

I have a pushbutton ("next"), I want to show next image when push button is pressed instead of taking user input.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I will try to rephrase and modify a bit: you want to draw a rectangle **only** if one clicks on the axes or image.

Therefore:
First of all I would suggest to put the *getrect*-part into another function. This function should only be triggered if one clicks on the image. The so called "ButtownDownFcn" seems to be suitable for this job. When using GUIDE, you will find it double-clicking on the axes within the property-inspector that is popping up.
Then put the *getrect*-part into this function:

```
function axes1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
rect_cord = getrect(handles.axes1);
rectangle('Curvature', [0 0],'Position', [rect_cord],'EdgeColor',[1 0 0]);
```

Now I thought that this is all that has to be done. But testing this with a plot or image within the axes prooved me wrong :o

Sadly one has to redirect the children of the axes to this function, because by default, it is only assigned to the background of the axes (=the blank axes).

by searching the net, I found the following solution here:
[Matlab in Chemical Engineering: Interacting with your graph through mouse clicks](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/11/22/interacting-with-your-graph-through-mouse-clicks/)

It works like this:
when plotting the image, you have to add the line

```
% and we also have to attach the function to the children, in this
% case that is the line in the axes.
set(get(gca,'Children'),'ButtonDownFcn', @mouseclick_callback)
```

Hope that helps!